# Can i add a button that allows notifications permission instead of opening app settings? (Flutter, iOS/Android)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, push-notification

I heard that after the user denies Notifications permission the only way to allow it is to send the user to the app settings to change it manually, is this true?
Or is there any way to implement a button that when the user clicks it allows Notifications permission?

Comment: If the user declines by pressing "don't show again", then yes, the only way to enable it is by going to the app settings yourself.

Comment: On iOS you get to ask the user once. If they say no then they have to change it in settings. You can show your own alert that provides a button that opens your app's settings but you can't show the actual permissions alert again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications) indicates that the prompt will not be shown again.

> "The first time your app makes this authorization request, the system prompts the user to grant or deny the request and records the user’s response. Subsequent authorization requests don’t prompt the user."

If the notifications permission is important to your app and you have reason to think a user might decline the first time, you can prompt them with your own dialog first, offering two options: Not Yet / Allow. If they tap Allow, then formally request permission and have iOS prompt them.